# Has disabling TDataset.ObjectView side-effects?

Tags: delphi, access-violation, vcl, tclientdataset, delphi-10-seattle

Today I stumbled over the [adt field types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Displaying_ADT_and_Array_Fields) in Delphi Datasets. We use custom client datasets to bind objects to datasets in our views. With that dataset and our custom derivation of `TDbGrid` and enabled FastMM4 full debug mode we get an access violation with the following stack trace:

```
System.Generics.Collections.TListHelper.DoIndexOfFwd4((kein Wert))
System.Classes.TComponent.FreeNotification($7F961CE0)
Vcl.DBGrids.TColumn.SetField($7F971700)
Vcl.DBGrids.TColumn.GetField
Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.Notification($7F971220,???)
System.Classes.TComponent.RemoveFreeNotifications
System.Classes.TComponent.Destroy
Data.DB.TField.Destroy
System.TObject.Free
Data.DB.TFields.ClearBase(True)
Data.DB.TFields.ClearAutomatic`
Data.DB.TDataSet.DestroyFields
Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.InternalClose
Data.DB.TDataSet.CloseCursor
Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.CloseCursor
Data.DB.TDataSet.SetActive(???)
```

After some debugging fun, i found out that the internal `FieldList` of the Dataset contains a already destroyed field. After doing some more reasearch, I found out that disabling property

```
DataSet.ObjectView
```

disables the internal `FieldList` and the access violation goes away.

As we don't use ADT field types, I suspect disabling it does no harm, but one never knows.

*Background*

I've had already a lot of problems with `TDataSet` and `TDbGrid`, starting with the inherent problems of the flickering scollbar in the grid and ending in corrupt BCD-Parameters for oracle databases. We updated from XE3 to DX10, the access violation did not occur before.

- I can not post the code of our custom dataset / custom grid
- we are freeing the dataset **before** the grid

Comment: Notice in the stack trace that `GetField` is calling `SetField` with the already disposed field which leads to the exception. I think that is caused because of `TField.LifeCycle` being `lcAutomatic` and `lcPersistent` because we define the display columns in the grid.

Comment: One reason for this question is that I'm assuming that the feature of adt field types is rarely used.I've never heard of it before..